# i cant find way its not sumitting the data to database

Tags: php

I am just starting out programming with php I started with a base system for member and pm system and I am adding to it but somewhere I messed it up and I dont see what I did, I added recaptcha to it and then it quite working and submitting the registration data to the database I have removed the recaptcha from it to see what I did wrong but after removed , still this does not work, I like some one else to look over the code cause I am missing what I did. the error of the code is it isnt sumiting the id, username, password, and email date to the database and it did before i commented out the avatar field i was having issuse with it in other files but i think i can get it working myself i just been trying to the code to submit the info (username password email)

```
<?php
include('config.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "[url=http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd]http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">[/url]
<html xmlns="[url=http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml]http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">[/url]
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link href="<?php echo $design; ?>/style.css" rel="stylesheet" title="Style" />
        <title>Sign up</title>
    </head>
    <body>
     <div class="header">
         <a href="<?php echo $url_home; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $design; ?>/images/logo.png" alt="Members Area" /></a>
   </div>
<?php
//We check if the form has been sent
if(isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['passverif'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['avatar']) and $_POST['username']!='')
{
//We remove slashes depending on the configuration
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
$_POST['username'] = stripslashes($_POST['username']);
$_POST['password'] = stripslashes($_POST['password']);
$_POST['passverif'] = stripslashes($_POST['passverif']);
$_POST['email'] = stripslashes($_POST['email']);
$_POST['avatar'] = stripslashes($_POST['avatar']);
}
//We check if the two passwords are identical
if($_POST['password']==$_POST['passverif'])
{
//We check if the password has 6 or more characters
if(strlen($_POST['password'])>=6)
{
//We check if the email form is valid
if(preg_match('#^(([a-z0-9!\#$%&\\\'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+\.?)*[a-z0-9!\#$%&\\\'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)@(([a-z0-9-_]+\.?)*[a-z0-9-_]+)\.[a-z]{2,}$#i',$_POST['email']))
{

//We protect the variables
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$avatar = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['avatar']);
//We check if there is no other user using the same username
$dn = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query('select id from users where username="'.$username.'"')); 
if($dn==0)
{
//We count the number of users to give an ID to this one
$dn2 = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query('select id from users'));
$id = $dn2+1;
//We save the informations to the databse
if(mysql_query('insert into users(id, username, password, email, avatar, signup_date) values ('.$id.', "'.$username.'", "'.$password.'", "'.$email.'", "'.$avatar.'", "'.time().'")'))
{
//We dont display the form
$form = false;
?>
<div class="message">You have successfuly been signed up. You can log in.<br />
<a href="connexion.php">Log in</a></div>
<?php
}
else
{
//Otherwise, we say that an error occured
$form = true;
$message = 'An error occurred while signing up.';
}
}
else
{
//Otherwise, we say the username is not available
$form = true;
$message = 'The username you want to use is not available, please choose another one.';
}
}
else
{
//Otherwise, we say the email is not valid
$form = true;
$message = 'The email you entered is not valid.';
}
}
else
{
//Otherwise, we say the password is too short
$form = true;
$message = 'Your password must contain at least 6 characters.';
}
}
else
{
//Otherwise, we say the passwords are not identical
$form = true;
$message = 'The passwords you entered are not identical.';
}
}
else
{
$form = true;
}
if($form)
{
//We display a message if necessary
if(isset($message))
{
echo '<div class="message">'.$message.'</div>';
}
}
//We display the form

?>
<div class="content" align="center">
    <form action="sign_up.php" method="post">
        Please fill the following form to sign up:<br />
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <div class="center">
            <label for="username">Username</label><input type="text" name="username" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['username'])){echo htmlentities($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');} ?>" /><br />
            <label for="password">Password<span class="small">(6 characters min.)</span></label><input type="password" name="password" /><br />
            <label for="passverif">Password<span class="small">(verification)</span></label><input type="password" name="passverif" /><br />
            <label for="email">Email</label><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['email'])){echo htmlentities($_POST['email'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');} ?>" /><br />
            <!--<label for="avatar">Avatar<span class="small">(optional)</span></label><input type="text" name="avatar" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['avatar'])){echo htmlentities($_POST['avatar'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');} ?>" /><br />  -->
            <input type="submit" value="Sign up" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<?php
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [i need help finding the bug in my php file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21655991/i-need-help-finding-the-bug-in-my-php-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unhide this and it should work:

```
<label for="avatar">Avatar<span class="small">(optional)</span></label><input type="text" name="avatar" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['avatar'])){echo htmlentities($_POST['avatar'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');} ?>" /><br />
```

in other words remove the `<!--` and `-->`

this part is also incorrect... you cannot use commas in the condition.

```
if(isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['passverif'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['avatar']) and $_POST['username']!='')
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably caused by your method of assigning a new ID (number of rows + 1). If you have holes in your ID list, you would be (could be...) trying to insert a row with an already existing ID.

That would lead to an error but as you are not checking for / handling errors, you will not see that.

What you should do is:

- Use an auto-increment for the primary key of your table (the `id` I assume);
- Switch to PDO or mysqli and prepared statements (the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated);
- Add error handling. Using PDO or mysqli it is extremely easy to have your database calls throw exceptions so you will know exactly when and what goes wrong.

By the way, php also has a built-in function to check for a valid e-mail address, see [`filter_var`](http://php.net/filter_var).